# How to create External table in Azure without the location path exist

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, polybase

Is there anyway to create External table in Azure SQL DWH even though the location path mentioned in external table statement doesn't exist.

For eg:- location '/src/temp' doesn't exist still I want external table to be created.

```
create external table ext.dummy(
PERSON_ID   varchar(500) ,
ASSIGNMENT_ID varchar(500)
)
WITH 
(
    LOCATION='/src/temp',
    DATA_SOURCE = YasCdpBlobStorage,
    FILE_FORMAT = ExtTableTextFileFormat,
    REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,
    REJECT_VALUE = 0
);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.  The external location whether it is a folder or a filepath must exist *before* you create the external table.

Although the documentation does not state this explicitlly, it is implied by the term "actual", ie

> LOCATION = 'folder_or_filepath'
>
> Specifies the folder or the file path
> and file name for the **actual** data in Hadoop or Azure blob storage.